# jquery form bind or index

Tags: jquery

I would like to specify a better code which will trigger a input radio and execute dedicated textfield.

Here's what i am talking about (sorry im not that very good at jquery so pls pardon me).
i post 2 samples only aside from original 32 questionnaires that are listed in my code.

```
        <table width="817" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="317" height="25">1. &nbsp;Use of adjoining property</td>
            <td width="10" height="25">:</td>
            <td width="480" height="25">
                <input type="radio" name="no1" value="Yes" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="no1" value="No" />No
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="notes">
            <td height="25" align="right">Notes</td>
            <td height="25">:</td>
            <td height="25">
                <input name="notes1" type="text" id="notes1" size="65" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td height="25">3. Access to dirt or paved road</td>
            <td height="25">:</td>
            <td height="25">
                <input type="radio" name="no3" id="radio8" value="Yes" />Yes
                <input type="radio" name="no3" id="radio9" value="No" />No
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="notes">
            <td height="25" align="right">Notes</td>
            <td height="25">:</td>
            <td height="25">
                <input name="notes3" type="text" id="notes3" size="65" value="" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

i did try to create each jquery but wanted to simplify the code.

```
              var notes = $('tr.notes');
            notes.hide();

            $('input[value="Yes"]').click(function () {
                notes.slideDown();
          });
```

i did do some research here but can't elaborate the structure. i appreciate your help. many thanks.

Comment: Any reason you're storing `$('tr.notes')` in a variable, and then just not use it?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, i will update it to my current code. i was still trying to configure my codes might be overlooked to it while pasting it here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will try to detect if the input radio is changed, it will detect if the clicked it will check the value and show the notes.

```
        $('.notes').hide();

        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                 $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideDown();
             } else {
                 $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideUp();
             }
      });
```

Please check this : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5aJWh/4/)

Comment: hi, i appreciate your idea, but after i did it, i keeps all .notes open at the time after i click the radio. in this, it should be per question, 1 notes textfield will slidedown...