# Multiple questionnaire

Tags: jquery, html

i did asked this before, but my client wanted to create a little functionality over the questionnaires. he wants all "Notes text-field" will be hidden if it is empty. it will be visible only if the "Notes text-field" have value. also the Yes / No radio button need to be updated / checked as well if there's a value or no value. here's the previous code that "insomniac" did.

```
$('.notes').hide();
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
  if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideDown();
  } else {
    $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideUp();
  }
});
```

however, i need to validate first the text-field if there's a value (actually 1 to 33 text-field will be use here and most of it will have value).

```
var vals = $('.notes input[type="text"]').val(); 
if(vals == "") {
  console.log('negative');
  $('tr.notes').slideUp();
} else {
  console.log('positive');
  $('.query input[value="Yes"]').attr({
    checked: "checked"
  });
  $('tr.notes').slideDown();
}
```

here's the original format of what i am discussing... [jQuery Bind or Index Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393128/jquery-form-bind-or-index) and [Insomniac Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5aJWh/4/)

Comment: *When* do you do the text field validation and slide up?  Text fields have to be visible when empty at some point right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some research and non-stop working the script. i finally decide to update the code into basic settings. "im not a programmer" actually...

```
$(".report-notes fieldset").each(function (i) {
i = i+1;
$(this).addClass("item"+i);
$('.item'+i+' input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes') {
        $('.item'+i+' .notes').slideDown();
    } else {
        $('.item'+i+' .notes').slideUp();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var notes = $('.item'+i+' .notes input[type="text"]').val();
    if(notes === '') {
        console.log('walang laman');
        $('.item'+i+' .notes').hide();
    } else {
        console.log('meron laman');
        $('.item'+i).find('input[value="Yes"]').attr({
            checked: "checked"
        });
        $('.item'+i+' .notes').slideDown();
    }
});
});
```

[Updated Fiddle Source](http://dogandrooster.com/clients/_snippets/jquery-val.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the length of the `.html()` and remove it accordingly from the view.

```
if ($(element).html().length == 0)
    $(element).hide();
```

If the notes are going to be loaded statically when the document loads, awesome, you just need to do this:

```
$('.notes').each(function(){
    if ($(this).html().length == 0)
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Else, if you are loading them dynamically, once you load them, check for the emptiness, using the first code.

Answer (score 1):

//Set the focus to the input and that way we can check in the blur event anything is entered.

```
        $('.notes').hide();

        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
                 $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideDown(); 
                $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').find('input').focus();                                
             } else {
                 $(this).closest('tr').next('tr.notes').slideUp();
             }
      });
```

//blur event tied up to all inputs

```
      $('input').blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length == 0){       
    $(this).closest('tr.notes').slideUp();
      }
     });
```

//updated the fiddle